# Execute code on cancel confirm navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload, window.onunload

I am using a simple on before unload script to ask the user if they are sure they want to leave the page.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    var message = "Confirm message.",
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e){e.returnValue = message;}
    return message;
};
```

Is there any way that I can run a function for if they hit cancel (navigation) or if they hit confirm (navigation)

Thanks :)

Comment: Try to use this https://github.com/codedance/jquery.AreYouSure

Answer (score 1):

You can hack with the `setTimeout` function:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    var message = "Confirm message.",
        e = e || window.event;

    if (e) { 
        e.returnValue = message; 
    }

    setTimeout(function () {
        alert("oh, Im after beforeonload function!");
    }, 1);

    return message;
};
```